# NullPointerException during AsyncTask in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

I have made the following activity class for making a listview.

But I have got NPE while initiating it. The java file and logcat are given below:

Activity Class

```
public class CategoryListActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener{
     //URL to get JSON Array
    private static String url = "http://code-explore.com/app/webroot/sp-codeexplore/getCategoryList.php?platform=Android";

    //JSON Node Names 
    private static final String TAG_CATEGORY = "categories";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "cat_id";
    private static final String TAG_TITLE = "cat_title";
    private static final String TAG_NO = "total_apps";

    JSONArray categories = null;

    public final static String CAT_ID = "com.smartmux.codeexplore.MESSAGE";

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);



ListView listView;
List<RowItem> rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.category);

    new SM_AsyncTask().execute(url);

}

    public void returnHome(View view) {
        onBackPressed();
    }



    class SM_AsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<RowItem>> {
         ProgressDialog pDialog=null;

     @Override
     protected void onPreExecute() {

            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();       
            }

    @Override
    protected List<RowItem> doInBackground(
            String... params) {
         // Creating new JSON Parser
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // Getting JSON from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

        try {
            // Getting JSON Array
            categories = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CATEGORY);

            for (int i = 0; i < categories.length(); i++) {
              JSONObject c = categories.getJSONObject(i);
              String title = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);
              String number = c.getString(TAG_NO);
              String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
              list.add(id);


              RowItem item = new RowItem(title, number);
              rowItems.add(item);


            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return rowItems;
    }

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(List<RowItem> result) {

    pDialog.dismiss();

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listCategory);
    ArrayAdapterForCategory adapter = new ArrayAdapterForCategory(this,
            R.layout.row_cat_list, result);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {

        String catId = list.get(position);
        Intent intent = new Intent(CategoryListActivity.this, AppListActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(CAT_ID, catId);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

**LogCat**

```
12-03 08:36:59.370: E/AndroidRuntime(2082): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-03 08:36:59.370: E/AndroidRuntime(2082): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.smartmux.codeexplore/com.smartmux.codeexplore.CategoryListActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-03 08:36:59.370: E/AndroidRuntime(2082):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
12-03 08:36:59.370: E/AndroidRuntime(2082):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
12-03 08:36:59.370: E/AndroidRuntime(2082):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-03 08:36:59.370: E/AndroidRuntime(2082):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
12-03 08:36:59.370: E/AndroidRuntime(2082):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-03 08:36:59.370: E/AndroidRuntime(2082):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-03 08:36:59.370: E/AndroidRuntime(2082):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
12-03 08:36:59.370: E/AndroidRuntime(2082):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-03 08:36:59.370: E/AndroidRuntime(2082):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-03 08:36:59.370: E/AndroidRuntime(2082):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
12-03 08:36:59.370: E/AndroidRuntime(2082):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-03 08:36:59.370: E/AndroidRuntime(2082):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-03 08:36:59.370: E/AndroidRuntime(2082): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-03 08:36:59.370: E/AndroidRuntime(2082):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:146)
12-03 08:36:59.370: E/AndroidRuntime(2082):     at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:103)
12-03 08:36:59.370: E/AndroidRuntime(2082):     at android.app.AlertDialog.resolveDialogTheme(AlertDialog.java:143)
12-03 08:36:59.370: E/AndroidRuntime(2082):     at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:98)
12-03 08:36:59.370: E/AndroidRuntime(2082):     at android.app.ProgressDialog.<init>(ProgressDialog.java:77)
12-03 08:36:59.370: E/AndroidRuntime(2082):     at com.smartmux.codeexplore.CategoryListActivity.<init>(CategoryListActivity.java:39)
12-03 08:36:59.370: E/AndroidRuntime(2082):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
12-03 08:36:59.370: E/AndroidRuntime(2082):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
12-03 08:36:59.370: E/AndroidRuntime(2082):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
12-03 08:36:59.370: E/AndroidRuntime(2082):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
12-03 08:36:59.370: E/AndroidRuntime(2082):     ... 11 more
```

Basically the problem will occur when the `AsyncTask` is called.

Comment: Initialize progress dialog,on declaration pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change to

```
ProgressDialog pDialog;
ListView listView;
List<RowItem> rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.category);
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this); // initialize in onCreate
```

Remove

```
ProgressDialog pDialog=null; // already declared
```

in Asynctask

Also

```
 @Override
 protected void onPreExecute() {
 super.onPreExcute()
```

And

```
 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(List<RowItem> result) {
 super.onPostExecute(result);
 listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listCategory);
 ArrayAdapterForCategory adapter = new ArrayAdapterForCategory(CategoryListActivity.this,
        R.layout.row_cat_list, result);
 listView.setAdapter(adapter);
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(CategoryListActivity.this);
 }
```

Change this

```
  return rowItems;
}
}
```

To

```
  return rowItems;
}
```

Also change. You have misplaces `}`

```
      startActivity(intent);
     }
 }
```

To

```
      startActivity(intent);
      }
    } 
 }
```

Comment: Yes, it stop the NPE, but I am facing another problem now, the progressDialog is appearing for a long time and won't stop. Could you please tell me why?

Comment: @CrazyLearner check the code in doinbackground. see if it is taking long time.

Comment: I cant put "super.onPostExecute(result)" method because it shows an error saying "the method is undefined for the type activity"..:(

Comment: @CrazyLearner check your closing } brackets. onPostExecute is for asynctask

Comment: @CrazyLearner you have a misplaced `}` and onPostExecute should be within asynctask class. remove the    extra `}` at the end of `return null; } }`. check my edit now

Comment: @CrazyLearner declare variables outside `onCreate` within Activtiy class like progress dialog shown in my post. This is very basic stuff in java. It is initialized in `onCreate`. Since it is an instance variable it is available in inner class also.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's working nicely by following your instructions..:). Sorry for my previous comment, I misinterpreted your last comment.

Answer (score 1):

In Asynctask remove this line:

> ProgressDialog pDialog=null; Or init progress dialog after